# Is 'fsck error on boot' hardware related or a bug?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-corruption

I bought a Razer Blade Stealth a week ago, took windows off and installed Ubuntu 17.10. Used until today when it started saying that my hard disk was write protected while I tried to save simple files. Then I reboot and this happens:

```
fsck error on boot: /dev/...: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

for my root partition. I found several answers here telling me to run `fsck`. I did and it fixed for some time, but then the error happened again.

I just want to know if this is hardware or software related, and if I should worry, or if this is just a bug in the 17.10 version. I'm downloading 17.04 now.

Comment: MOre likely than not hardware related. Backup any data you do not want to loose, then run smartmontools. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: When you "took windows off and installed Ubuntu 17.10" did you reformat the partitions to a Linux-native type, or leave them `FAT` or `NTFS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a hardware or a software problem. This is not a 17.10 bug, and installing 17.04 won't solve it.

First, as you've done before, lets check/repair your file system...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Once completed, and rebooted, start the `Disks` application. Select your disk in the left column, then click on the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data and run the tests. This will give you **some** indication about the condition of your hard disk.

Comment: The Smart Data & test options is gray, and there's no hamburger icon

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs did you remember to select the hard disk in the left column? If you did select the disk, then maybe the disk doesn't support SMART, but that would be very unusual for a new computer. The "hamburger" icon appears in the top titlebar of the Disks app window.

Comment: I would run fsck from a live usb rather than recovery mode. I would probably just skip to smartmontools as well. IMHO this is extremely unlikely to be a fsck bug as fsck "fixed" the problems (we are not getting a fsck error), but they recur. This is, in my experience, classic for impending hard drive failure.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs - Did  you back up your data yet ? If not, please back up any data you do not wish to loose as a first step .

Comment: Yes, all my data is backed up. This problem ocurred right after I installed Android Studio, but I don't know if there is a connection. And when I fixed with fcsk, the problem appeared again only when I closed and opened the notebook. When I installed ubuntu, it showed lots of problems with the closing/opening: mouse freezes after I close and open, and it started sleeping/waking randomly after this. All these problems were solved. Maybe this problem is also related to this, I don't know. There's no more disk problem after I reinstalled the OS, but I didn't close and open to see.

Comment: I'm going to stay with it opened for some days to see if the problem occurs again. If not, I'll test after closing/opening to see if that's what causes it.

Comment: by the way, gsmartcontrol can see the ssd, detect its name and some informations, but can't do any tests on it